# How to use QAndroidJniObject to call a Intent from Java

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, qandroidjniobject

- I want to use the rtl_tcp Driver for my App in Android to read Raw data from a usb Tv tuner.
- I found this source code https://github.com/martinmarinov/rtl_tcp_andro- and the guy has an App as driver at google play and anyone can call this App and can read raw data via tcp port.
- This is the App https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=marto.rtl_tcp_andro&hl=en

Now, i would like to call this drivers from my App, but i use QT. I found the classes QAndroidJNIObject to call java code. 
I found also at github.com/demantz/RFAnalyzer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mantz_it/rfanalyzer/MainActivity.java an example in java.

```
try { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("iqsrc://-a 127.0.0.1 -p 1234 -n 1"));
    startActivityForResult(intent, RTL2832U_RESULT_CODE); 
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
{
    Log.e(LOGTAG, "createSource: RTL2832U is not installed");
    ...
}
```

But i cannot find a way to write the right code in C++/Qt to make the equal call like the example in Java. I am not sure if this java code is correct or missing something.

Can someone help me ?

Also i want to ask if i can have a tcp connection with anet.h libs from Qt code?

Comment: Format and indent your code. Use Ctrl+K for code formatting, not ``.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [QJniAndroidObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html#isValid) class to create JNI objects and manipulate them. It's not always obvious but it works in the end. Your 9-line of Java will most likely end up to be a 50-line C++ code. I recommend that you transcode each line one by one and always check objects are valid ([QJniAndroidObject::isValid()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html#isValid)).

Here is an example creating an `Intent` and starting an activity:
[startActivity on Qt, nothing displays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351644/startactivity-on-qt-nothing-displays)

Try to write some code and post another SO question if it fails (syntax to create and manipulate `QJniAndroidObject` is not always obvious for C++ developers not familiar with Java).