# startActivity on Qt, nothing displays

Tags: android, qt

I coded like below. 
It seems to display the Android Setting menu, but nothing comes out.
And I did not see any error or log about it. I don't know what happens after calling the `startActivity()`.

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod
                                     ("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative",
                                      "activity",
                                      "()Landroid/app/Activity;");

if(activity.isValid()){
    QAndroidJniObject p1 = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("com.android.settings");
    QAndroidJniObject p2 = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("com.android.settings.DevelopmentSettings");

    QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent", "()V");

    if(p1.isValid() && p2.isValid() && intent.isValid()){

         qDebug() << "intent create OK and startActivity";

         intent.callObjectMethod("setClassName",
                                         "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;",
         p1.object<jobject>(),
         p2.object<jobject>());
         intent.callObjectMethod("startActivity",
                     "(Landroid/content/Intent;)V",
                     intent.object<jobject>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`startActivity` is a method of [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) class, not [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). So it needs to be called on `activity` object, not on `intent`.

```
intent.callObjectMethod("startActivity", "(Landroid/content/Intent;)V", intent.object<jobject>());
```

must be replace by:

```
activity.callObjectMethod("startActivity", "(Landroid/content/Intent;)V", intent.object<jobject>());
```

Here is the working code to open Android settings menu:

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");   //activity is valid
if ( activity.isValid() )
{
    // Equivalent to Jave code: 'Intent intent = new Intent();'
    QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent","()V");
    if ( intent.isValid() )
    {
        QAndroidJniObject param1 = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("com.android.settings");
        QAndroidJniObject param2 = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("com.android.settings.DevelopmentSettings");

        if ( param1.isValid() && param2.isValid() )
        {
            // Equivalent to Jave code: 'intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.DevelopmentSettings");'
            intent.callObjectMethod("setClassName","(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;",param1.object<jobject>(),param2.object<jobject>());

            // Equivalent to Jave code: 'startActivity(intent);'
            activity.callObjectMethod("startActivity","(Landroid/content/Intent;)V",intent.object<jobject>());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then please vote up and accept the answer (that's how it works on stackoverflow). Thanks.